# why this code not storing data in database and showing error instead?

Tags: django, django-models

i am working on some django code in my application but it's showing TypeError.

models.py

```
class Board(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Topic(models.Model):
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    board = models.ForeignKey(Board, related_name='topics',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    starter = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='topics',on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Post(models.Model):
    message = models.TextField(max_length=4000)
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, related_name='posts',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='posts',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    updated_by = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, related_name='+',on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Topic(models.Model):
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Post(models.Model):
    updated_by = models.ForeignKey(User,null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="+")
```

views.py

```
def board_topics(request, pk):
    board = get_object_or_404(Board, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'topics.html', {'board': board})

def new_topic(request, pk):
    board = get_object_or_404(Board, pk=pk)

    if request.method == 'POST':

        subject = request.POST.get('subject','')
        message = request.POST.get('message','')

        user = User.objects.first()


        topic = Topic.objects.create(
            subject=subject,
            board=board,
            starter=user
        )

        post = Post.objects.create(
            message=message,
            topic=topic,
            created_by=user
        )

        return redirect('board_topics', pk=board.pk)                                                                                        

    return render(request, 'new_topic.html', {'board': board})
```

Error:-
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42Xjh.png)

Comment: Why do you have two class definitions for each of Topic and Post? Only the last one will be used.

Answer (score 2):

Delete these redundant models

```
class Topic(models.Model):
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Post(models.Model):
    updated_by = models.ForeignKey(User,null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="+")
```